androidx.profileinstaller.ProfileInstallReceiver Warning in MobSF Scan - Not Defined in My Manifest
I’m working on an Android project and during a MobSF scan, I received a warning related to androidx.profileinstaller.ProfileInstallReceiver, indicating that it's accessible to other applications due to being exported. However, I haven’t defined this receiver in my app’s AndroidManifest.xml.
From what I understand, this receiver is part of the androidx.profileinstaller library, which I haven’t directly added to my project. It might be included through another dependency.
Here’s the warning from MobSF:
A Broadcast Receiver is found to be shared with other apps on the device therefore leaving it accessible to any other application on the device. It is protected by a permission which is not defined in the analyzed application...
How can I address this warning in MobSF, especially if I don’t need or use this ProfileInstallReceiver directly in my app? Is there a way to prevent MobSF from flagging it or to override the receiver’s configuration in my app so that it’s not a security concern?

Since .ProfileInstallReceiver has already specified a permission requirement android.permission.DUMP, which is a signature/privileged permission defined in android framework
so it is safe to just leave it alone, MobSF just showed a false positive result for you,
